# Jar I am I building is not finding jar dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am using intellij to create a jar file. I have 5 jar files in the project as dependencies. I have added these 5 jar files in the artifact setting as follows.

[image]

I am able to run the project fine in intellij but when I try to run the jar I created it says it cannot find the class of one of the jars, which does not make sense to me. I have even tried making the jar with editing the classpath in the artifacts settings. Any help would be appreciative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of the jars will only works well for your IDE because the IDE configured the path environment for testing, but once you run your code without IDEs, the path will follow your default setting with the system environmental variables.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me with googling for a better answer. For those interested one way to do it was to put the dependent jars in the java/exertions.

Comment: Yes, That will also work well. Just mentioned if you do that way, you may put the jars in the folder again once the java version updated or using different runtime libs.